# zooming/blowup and panning option in chart.js on category scales

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

i am using chart.js for making the charts. i have successfully done the graph things. Just i want a help in this regard that sometimes there could be just 30-40 points to plot. but usually there are about 1000 points.

So what is the good option which i can use for better analysis for this reporting tool. Like is there any option of blow up specific point or i can use a scroll to scroll my chart and expand it horizontally, a very large.

this is my chart image.

[image]

u can see there are many points and all are congested. i want to know what is the suitable solution.

This is my chart configuration in which i have set it to the responsive.

```
var options = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
        display: true,
        position: "top",
        text: label,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontColor: "#111"
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
            fontColor: "#333",
            fontSize: 16
        }
    },
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'single',
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                var multistringText = ['Assay Value: '+tooltipItems.yLabel];
                multistringText.push('Assigned Value: '+assigned_value[tooltipItems.index]);
                multistringText.push('Sample ID: '+sample_id[tooltipItems.index]);
                return multistringText;
            }
        }
    },
```

**Update:** After searching and creating an issue on the official chartjs `git` repository . This is not possible for the category/simple x-axis lines. This mean you cannot add pan through the chart in this way using the category/simple scales on x-axis. however zooms still works fine. 
Editing this question for the future readers.

P.s: Leave a comment in case of negative voting.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`chartjs-plugin-zoom`](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom).  It is a plugin that adds the capability to zoom in/out and pan left/right/up/down to view the rest of your data that is not currently displayed on the zoomed chart.

Here is a live [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGabEK).

I'm not sure it will do exactly what you need, but its a great place to start (you can use this as a base and extend it to your needs).  This plugin is also developed/supported by the same team as chart.js.

Comment: let me check and view how to use it. Will try on my project. :) thankx any ways :)

Comment: also can you tell me if there is possible solution for it to zoom in at a specific point because it usually randomly zoom the chart

Comment: Im not sure if there is an option to do that.  Let me look at the source tomorrow and see if it can be added.

Comment: sure till then i will also try to search this thing

Comment: @jordanwillis I set up my chart.js zoom plugin but its giving me an error when my page loads. Its telling me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Undexpected token < chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js:7

Any thoughts?